# Class selectors is not working in my code - why?

Tags: css

Why doesn't the same class (.container) work for my form container? It works for other div elements that use the same class.

full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/3dadz9g1/embedded/result/

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/3dadz9g1/

CSS:

```
.h-nav,
.container,
.images{
    width:95%;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML that does not work:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>FORM</h2>
</div>
```

See full HTML / CSS in the fiddle.

Comment: The problem is either in your html, or in your css.

Comment: What class are you referring to? I opened the jsfiddle, but didn't see what you refer to.

Comment: That check on not allowing fiddle links to be posted without relevant code being in question is there for a reason. Please don't work-around that check by formatting links as code blocks.

Comment: `Why same Class` which class? `(for centering content) is not for another html elements` which elements? ` it is working for previous elements? ` what previous elements?

Comment: .container class is used for the FORM constant. If you see the link then you will the last iteam is not centering 
http://jsfiddle.net/3dadz9g1/embedded/result/

Comment: I've edited the question. Need a peer review though to publish it.

Comment: Add a `text-align: center;` to your `.container` css. Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3dadz9g1/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lack a closing `</a>` :
http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/3dadz9g1/1/

```
    <a href="#" class="image-grid-square">
        <img src="images/bboy.png" alt=""></a>
</section>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>FORM</h2>
    </div>
    <footer>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bro , Easy things make so trouble . Then need 3rd person to solve this @Preben

Comment: @user3689456 Thank you. If this solved your problem I kindly ask you to mark this as the answer. Thank you.